# quiero poner, modificar y recuperar comentarios en sqlite, a la base de datos, a las tablas y a las columnas

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Por ahora estoy poniendo comentarios a las columnas de las tablas solamente.

Para poner comentarios en el momento de crearla estoy usando esta query:

```
CREATE TABLE KBase (
    n1tId INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL /* ####### AutoNumerico  */, 
    a1tNombrePrograma        VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tNombreTabla           VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tNombreArchivoDBF      VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tLetra                 VARCHAR (2)  /* CC Texto  */, 
    a1tCampoNombreDBF        VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tCampoNombreTabla      VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tCampoTipo             VARCHAR (1)  /* C Texto  */, 
    n1tCampoLargo            VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    n1tCampoDecimales        VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    a1tCreoPicture           VARCHAR (400)/* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    n1tManteOrden            VARCHAR (3)  /* ### Numerico  */, 
    a1tManteTitulo           VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tMantePicture          VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */,
    n1tManteTamano           VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    n1tManteDecimales        VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    l1tManteMuestro          BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    n1tAltaOrden             VARCHAR (3)  /* ### Numerico  */, 
    a1tAltaTitulo            VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tAltaPicture           VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    n1tAltaTamano            VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    n1tAltaDecimales         VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    l1tAltaMuestro           BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    l1tAltaGets              BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    n1tBajaOrden             VARCHAR (3)  /* ### Numerico  */, 
    a1tBajaTitulo            VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tBajaPicture           VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    n1tBajaTamano            VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    n1tBajaDecimales         VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    l1tBajaMuestro           BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    n1tFichaOrden            VARCHAR (3)  /* ### Numerico  */, 
    a1tFichaTitulo           VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tFichaPicture          VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    n1tFichaTamano           VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    n1tFichaDecimales        VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    l1tFichaMuestro          BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    n1tModifOrden            VARCHAR (3)  /* ### Numerico  */, 
    a1tModifTitulo           VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tModifPicture          VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    n1tModifTamano           VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    n1tModifDecimales        VARCHAR (5)  /* ##### Numerico  */, 
    l1tModifMuestro          BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    l1tModifGets             BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    a1tRelacionTabla         VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tRelacionTablaCampo    VARCHAR (20) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    l1tOrdenado              BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    l1tRequerido             BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    a1tAntes                 VARCHAR (80) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tDespues               VARCHAR (80) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tValid                 VARCHAR (80) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    a1tValidacion            VARCHAR (80) /* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC Texto  */, 
    l1tUnico                 BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    l1tPrimarykey            BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */, 
    l1tAutoincrement         BOOLEAN      /* # YesNo  */
)
```

Quisiera leer esos comentarios y modificarlos (uno a uno) que query usaria en cada caso ?

En la tabla se guardan datos, que se insertan, eliminan y modifican como es habitual.

Con esta orden creo la tabla y le pongo un comentario o descripción a cada columna.

Con ztree (herramienta que permite entre otras cosas visualizar hexadecimalmente el contenido de los archivos(http://www.ztree.com/html/ztreewin.htm)) veo que dicha información es guardada.

Lo que deseo es editar, eliminar, visualizar estos comentarios, para ello necesito la query.

Los comentarios es lo que está a la derecha de cada linea donde defino cada columna, colocados entre: /* */

En las bases de datos ms-access es posible agregar una descripción a las columnas (las columnas son llamadas campos), luego dicha descripción es pasible de ser editada posteriormente.

Comment: ¿Los comentarios que hay en ese query? O te refieres a _"asumiendo"_ que tenemos datos en esa tabla y quieres modificarlos uno a uno?

Comment: No queda claro qué se está preguntando; por favor pon una explciación más completa y algún ejemplo.

Comment: Ayudanos a ayudarte, parece que a varios miembros de la comunidad no les ha quedado claro que es lo que necesitas. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para agregar mas detalles sobre lo que quieres lograr para que puedas obtener mejores respuestas a tu pregunta.

Comment: @NaCl, lo que quiero es editar, eliminar los comentarios que están en esa query, los datos ya sé como editarlos

Comment: @HugoMariño Pasa que los comentarios no se editan con un query, los comentarios son para entendimiento del desarrollador, es decir, si tienes un código que es dificil de leer, lo comentas especificando lo que hace. En tu caso, seria la documentación de para que sirve cada campo en la tabla Y eso no se puede cambiar haciendo un query.

Comment: @NaCl, yo pensaba que los comentarios solo formaban parte de la query en sqlite, pero en ms-access existen esos comentarios y son incorporados en la base de datos, cuando la creas en vista de diseño los introduces y si entras en vista de diseño los ves nuevamente y los puedes editar, en sqlite yo comprobé que dichos comentarios son incrustados en el archivo, pero no sé en que tabla son guardados, debe de ser en alguna tabla propia de sqlite de tipo sqlite_..., tal vez puedas crear esta tabla en una base de datos tuya y con el ztree visualizar que los datos estan guardados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probando un programa manejador de archivos sqlite:
SQlite Expert Personal 3.5.67.2487 (hay versiones mas nuevas)

Teniendo abierta una base de datos y teniendo seleccionada una tabla, observé que al apretar DDL me muestra la sentencia de creación de la tabla, entonces deduje que es posible mediante un comando obtenerla.

Buscando en google por DDL, encontre una query para obtenerla:

```
    select sql from sqlite_master where type ='table';
```

Esta es la respuesta que esperaba obtener !!!

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a [esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7426289/1065197), al parecer SQLite almacena los comentarios que coloques en tus sentencias DDL (Lenguaje de Definición de Datos). Esto es, si tienes un script como este:

```
sqlite> create table KBase (
```

...> id integer unique primary key autoincrement, /* prueba de comentario */
   ...> valor varchar(20) /* otro comentario de prueba */ );

Al ejecutar el comando `.schema` te devuelve el esquema de la tabla con sus comentarios:

```
sqlite> .schema KBase
CREATE TABLE KBase (
id integer unique primary key autoincrement, /* prueba de comentario */
valor varchar(20) /* otro comentario de prueba */ );
```

Los comentarios funcionan inclusive si alteras la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
sqlite> alter table KBase
   ...> add column otro varchar(20) /*intentando agregar comentario*/
   ...> ;
```

Y volviendo a ejecutar `.schema` da como resultado:

```
sqlite> .schema KBase
CREATE TABLE KBase (
id integer unique primary key autoincrement, /* prueba de comentario */
valor varchar(20) /* otro comentario de prueba */ , otro varchar(20) /*intentando agregar comentario*/);
```

Si necesitas modificar algún comentario, significa que debes cambiar el DDL, es decir, que debes eliminar (`DROP`) la tabla y volver a crearla con los comentarios adecuados. De todas formas, me parece que no es una buena práctica estar cambiando constantemente los comentarios de una tabla.

Comment: si quisiera obtener el schema mediante query, como sería ?

Comment: SQLite no soporta lo que dices. Solo lo soporta mediante la sentencia `.schema`.